# Entity Framework: How do we map a composite key in a third entity class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out how to make this work.

I have three entity classes like so:

```
public class Manufacturer {
    public Manufacturer () {
        MyProducts = new HashSet<Product> ();
    }

    public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> MyProducts { get; set; }
}

public class Product {
    public Product () {
        MyPromotions = new HashSet<Promotion> ();
    }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Promotion> MyPromotions { get; set; }
}

public class Promotion {
    public Promotion () {
    }

    public int PromotionId { get; set; }

    public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

And their configurations are like so:

```
public class ManufacturerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Manufacturer> {
    public ManufacturerConfiguration () {
        ToTable ("tbl_Manufacturers");

        HasKey (mfr => mfr.ManufacturerName)
            .Property (t => t.ManufacturerName)
            .HasMaxLength (64)
            .HasColumnName ("key_ManufacturerName")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption (DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        HasMany (m => m.MyProducts)
            .WithRequired (p => p.Manufacturer)
            .HasForeignKey (p => p.ManufacturerName)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete (false);
    }
}

public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product> {
    public ProductConfiguration () {
        ToTable ("tbl_Products");

        HasKey (p => new { p.ProductName, p.ManufacturerName});

        Property (t => t.ProductName)
            .HasMaxLength (64)
            .HasColumnName ("key_ProductName")
            .IsRequired ();

        Property (t => t.ManufacturerName)
            .HasMaxLength (64)
            .HasColumnName ("fkey_ManufacturerName")
            .IsRequired ();
    }
}

public class PromotionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Promotion> {
    public PromotionConfiguration () {
        ToTable ("tbl_Promotions");

        HasKey (promotion => promotion.PromotionId)
            .Property (promotion => promotion.PromotionId)
            //.HasMaxLength (64)
            .HasColumnName ("key_PromotionName")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption (DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}
```

The Manufacturer entity is a standalone one, ie., it has no foreign keys. The Product entity refers to the Manufacturer class, and its name field, ProductName, *must* be qualified with the Manufacturer name to avoid name collisions. Consequently, I have defined its key as a composite of both the ManufacturerName and its own ProductName. Works well so far.

The problem is that I need to reference this in the Promotion entity class (assuming that a single promotion promotes only one product). I have tried several ways in which to create a foreign key reference to the product; however, that won't work as Product's key itself is a composite. And EF won't allow me to specify only Product's key (Error: "The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical".)

I have tried several approaches to define a composite foreign key (with both components of the foreign key belonging to different entities), but with no success.

Comment: I highly recommend [surrogate keys](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html) as you have on the promotion table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to configure `{ProductName, ManufacturerName}` in `Promotion` as FK to `Product`.

You could do that in either `ProductConfiguration`:

```
HasMany(prod => prod.MyPromotions)
    .WithRequired(prom => prom.Product)
    .HasForeignKey(prom => new { prom.ProductName, prom.ManufacturerName });
```

or `PromotionConfiguration`:

```
HasRequired(prom => prom.Product)
    .WithMany(prod => prod.MyPromotions)
    .HasForeignKey(prom => new { prom.ProductName, prom.ManufacturerName });
```

(but please don't do that in both - one reason I don't like the `EntityTypeConfiguration` based setup is the need to determine where to put the relationship configuration, since it logically applies to *two entity types*).

Additionally, I would suggest removing the `Manufacturer` navigation property from `Promotion`. While you can configure a separate FK to `Manufacturer` through `ManufacturerName`, it's redundant and is causing multiple cascade paths - the same information could be obtained through `Promotion.Product.Manufacturer`.

Comment: It worked (y) And thanks for the advice on the navigation property.